# How to find the maximum value from the same row in a table?

Tags: mysql, sql

I am newbie to `SqL`. I am trying to find the maximum value of a `row`. For example:

I have a table with 3 rows named as `id` ,`total_1` , `total_2` and `total_3`.

I want to find out which of the three totals has the maximum value. Is it any way to do so?

Comment: do you need to get the max value of those 3 columns or do you need to know in which column the max value is contained?

Comment: Suppose total_1 =3, total_2=4 and total_3=5 then I must get the value of total_3

Comment: I am trying with  MySql

Comment: use greatest function

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This can be done using the `greatest` function:

```
select id, greatest(total_1, total_2, total_3)
from your_table
```